# Error with bundling and minification

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

I know that bundling and minification only works when not in debug mode.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to run my SPA, it works fine.

However, if I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to enable debugging, even when `debug=false` on the `web.config`, my page does not load correctly. When I checked the developer tools, [I found this](http://screencast.com/t/oip3RcgZC).

If I check my code and my scripts library, it seems OK.

**BundleConfig.cs**:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
  AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(bundles.IgnoreList);

  bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/modernizr")
        .Include("~/scripts/modernizr-{version}.js"));

  bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
     .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js")
     .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
     .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.js")
     .Include("~/scripts/toastr.js"));

  bundles.Add(
   new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
     .Include("~/Content/ie10mobile.css") // Must be first. IE10 mobile viewport fix
     .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
     .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css")
     .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
     .Include("~/Content/toastr.css")
     .Include("~/Content/styles.css")
   );
}
```

And the VS studio structure, the [files are there](http://screencast.com/t/vzgB9uLX).

If I check my index.cshtml

```
@using System.Web
@using System.Web.Optimization
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CCJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <script language="javascript">
        // Must be first. IE10 mobile viewport fix
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            var mq = "@@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}";
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mq));
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/modernizr")
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="applicationHost">
            @RenderPage("_splash.cshtml")
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")
        <script src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="App/Main"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line to your BundleConfig.cs

```
//note: you can map isCompressionEnabled to your webconfig appSettings
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = isCompressionEnabled;
```